# Linq query and get aggregated result + extra info

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm creating a linq query to get some data that will return a list of emails and some other info.

I've created the query so that i get the emails that i want, and the info. The thing is, it's possible that the info will be the same for more than 1 email.

I want to know what's the linq way to get a resultset that returns me something like

```
email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com  |   INFO
email3@domain.com  |   INFO2
email4@domain.com,email5@domain.com,email6@domain.com,email3@domain.com  |   INFO3
```

With the first property being a csv list of emails.

The query that I have right now is something like this :

```
from user in context.Users
join ufa in context.UFAccesses on user equals ufa.User
join f in context.F on ufa.Feed equals f
join fp in context.FP on f equals fp.F
select new { thisUfa = fp.F.UFAccess.Where(ufaSearch => ufaSearch.User == user && ufaSearch.F == f).FirstOrDefault(), user.Email, fp.Title, fp.Content };
```

EDIT : some extra info to help the answerer. maybe there's a better way to do this. the main reason for the question is, since i'm getting this INFO several times (because it may correspond to more than 1 email), i'm getting innecessary data. later, i can do a loop in this resultset and for each info get a list of emails that correspond to it, but of course i'd like to get something more efficient and in linq if possible.

Comment: your question is not well worded. Are you trying to figure out how to format the objects returned by the query into a string?

Comment: What unnecessary data are you getting?  I don't understand what you need???

Comment: right now i'm getting (example)
email1 | INFO
email2 | INFO
email3 | INFO2
email3 | INFO3
email4 | INFO3
email5 | INFO3
email6 | INFO3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should solve your problem:

```
public class Something
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<Something>();
list.Add(new Something { Email = "email1", Info = "info1" });
list.Add(new Something { Email = "email2", Info = "info2" });
list.Add(new Something { Email = "email3", Info = "info3" });
list.Add(new Something { Email = "email4", Info = "info3" });
list.Add(new Something { Email = "email5", Info = "info3" });
list.Add(new Something { Email = "email6", Info = "info1" });

var groupedList = list.GroupBy(e => e.Info).Select(g => new { Info = g.Key, Emails = String.Join(",",g.Select(e => e.Email)) });
```

First we are grouping with `GroupBy(e => e.Info)` and then selecting group key (Info) and joined emails:

```
new { Info = g.Key, Emails = String.Join(",",g.Select(e => e.Email)) });
```

Comment: ok, so there's no other way but to create an intermediate class? i was trying to avoid that

Comment: `Something` class is just for this example purposes. You can do the same with result of EF query. You have to process it on code side (after query execution), because SQL Server doesn't have string aggregation functions.

Comment: fantastic, works like a charm. i love anonymous types a little bit more now :)